# Generate random samples for each sample length for a distribution

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter, statsmodels

My goal is to have draw 500 sample points, take its mean, and then do 6000 times from a distribution. Basically:

> Take sample lengths ranging from N = 1 to 500. For each sample length,
> draw 6000 samples and estimate the mean from each of the samples.
> Calculate the standard deviation from these means for each sample
> length, and show graphically that the decrease in standard deviation
> corresponds to a square root reduction.

I am trying to do this on a gamma distribution, but all of my standard deviations are coming out as zero... and I'm not sure why.

This is the program so far:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import gamma


# now taking random gamma samples 

stdevs = []
length = np.arange(1, 401,1)

mean=[]
for i in range(400):
    sample = np.random.gamma(shape=i,size=1000)
    mean.append(np.mean(sample))
    stdevs.append(np.std(mean))


      
   # then trying to plot the standard deviations but it's just a line.. 
   # thought there should be a decrease
    
plt.plot(length, stdevs,label='sampling') 
plt.show()
```

[image]

I thought there should be a decrease in the standard deviation, not an increase. What might I be doing wrong when trying to draw 1000 samples from a gamma distribution and estimate the mean and standard deviation?

Comment: As you increase the `shape` you increase the interval over which you draw your sample. Compare the x-axis ranges when you plot `plt.plot(x, gamma.pdf(x,2))` and `plt.plot(x, gamma.pdf(x,400))`. You will see that the distributions are over very different intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misusing shape.  Shape is the shape of the distribution not the number of independent draws.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Reproducible
gen = np.random.default_rng(20210513)

# Generate 400 (max sample size) by 1000 (number of indep samples)
sample = gen.gamma(shape=2, size=(400, 1000))
# Use cumsum to compute the cumulative sum
means = np.cumsum(sample, axis=0)
# Divid the cumsume by the number of observations used in each
# A little care needed to get broadcasting to work right
means = means / np.arange(1,401)[:,None]

# Compute the std dev using the observations in each row
stdevs = means.std(axis=1)

# Plot
plt.plot(np.arange(1,401), stdevs,label='sampling') 
plt.show()
```

This produces the pictire.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line `stdevs.append(np.std(sample.mean(axis=0)))`

This takes the standard deviation of a single value i.e. the mean of your `sample` array, so it will always be `0`.

You need to pass `np.std()` all the values in your sample not just its mean.

`stdevs.append(np.std(sample))` will give you your array of standard deviations for each sampling.